# Opening new tab programmatically without refreshing referring page?

Tags: javascript, html, tabs, dom-events

I have a page loaded via a POST request which opens another tab programmatically like this:

```
Object.assign(document.createElement("a"),
              { target: "_blank", href: "foo.html"}).click();
```

However, what happens is that in addition to opening the new tab, it also refreshes the original page, but it does so using a GET request instead of a POST request, which means I have lost all the POST parameters sent to the original page.

Is there any way to open the new tab without refreshing the referring page?

Comment: The current code you are showing won't cause the current page to refresh,.  I'm assuming your running this code on a Form, it's the form submitting that causes the refresh not this.  You can use `event.preventDefault` on your form to stop that.

Comment: Ah, of course! That's the solution. Many thanks. I will mark this up as the correct answer as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Keith wrote earlier:

> The current code you are showing won't cause the current page to refresh,. I'm assuming your running this code on a Form, it's the form submitting that causes the refresh not this. You can use event.preventDefault on your form to stop that.

This was indeed my problem, and calling event.preventDefault() solved it. Thanks, Keith!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `window.open` API for this (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open). Just call it like this `window.open('foo.html', '_blank');`

Comment: On some browsers this opens a new window, not a new tab. The way I do it works more reliably across browsers. And in any case, this wasn't the issue...